# Heroku PostgreSQL Studio not finding databases

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, postgresqlstudio

I'm making a new Django app on Heroku, and I added the "PostgreSQL Studio" add-on for running database creation scripts. It installed cleanly, it appears in the Heroku UI for each app, when I click it it's correctly trying to get to the correct database (powerful-waters-2373), but it opens a "Connect" modal with a Login button and an empty dropdown menu :(

The pgstudio instruction screens suggest that the database name should come through here: 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgstudio#provisioning-the-add-on

(Another reasonable guess would be a user, and I did create an auth_user record during database creation, but I'm not 100% sure if that update makes it to the production version of the db vs just locally- this is all pretty new for me)

This should be the easy part, but my forum searches have come up empty and apparently I got 'lucky' in a way that other people haven't.  Any ideas for what I can check/update to get started with this PostgreSQL Studio add-on?

Answer (score 0):

The format of the connection to Heroku Postgres has changed and we are working to modify PostgreSQL Studio to handle the change.

Comment: thanks!  No change yet- is there somewhere I can watch for updates?  (Or is there already a fix and I need to uninstall/reinstall for it to work?)

Comment: Just posting for posterity- this bug was fixed (now able to view/select the database name)- thanks!